# Converting LTCG binary library to x86 code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, x86-64

I work on a C++ project including tons of third party libraries, using Visual 2012. We have two main platforms ( two game consoles, using the same CPU :)). Our project links in 3.5seconds on one platform, and in 75seconds in the other one. After analysing, the huge difference is because some third party libraries are build with /GL. In the final link, because of that, the linker automatically switch to /LTCG mode to produce real x86 code. (and that's a long process).

My question: is there any way, work around, hack, to re-build the third party library WITHOUT /GL (so it will contain classic x86 code) to speed up the final link time? Obviously without requiring the source code!

Thanks in advance

Comment: have the same issue, did you find a solution?